# How to add every 2 characters in a pandas series df

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to split up the Gun_Time and Net_Time columns by adding a ':' after every 2 numbers.
I've tried some regex with a simple function but have been unable to come up with the correct solution to correctly insert a ':' after every 2 numbers.  How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda function and apply. Are you trying to convert these values into timestamps ?

```py
df.Gun_Time.astype(str).apply(lambda s: s[:2] + ':' + s[2:])
```

Comment: this worked beautifully, thank you! and yes into timestamps

Comment: the only other issue I have is that some of the columns have the following format: 00:00:00 - how would i solution you gave me on these columns? @Hugolmn

Comment: Do you want to keep them as they are or perform another transformation ?

Comment: So I have another column named "Final_Time" that is formatted in the following: "013453", so i would need to transform the column to look like "01:34:53".  I have tried modifying the solution you gave me but have not been able to solve this

Comment: This should do it : `df.Final_Time.astype(str).apply(lambda s: s[:2] + ':' + s[2:4] + ':' + s[4:)`